# Select a text node following an element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select (hide) **the date** in the following code?

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <h5>
    <strong>News header</strong> 2015-03-05
  </h5>
</div>
```

The problem is that the date has no id, no class nor a paragraph tag. Perhaps there's a way to use a [sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) or similar?

I don't have access to the html, just the css.

Comment: what is the css you tried ? if it is about styling

Comment: If you haven't noticed already, the system automatically inserts a link to the duplicate at the very top of your question. It was wholly unnecessary to edit it *again* to say "Resolved here" just to point to the very same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target it with *some* styling:

```css
.myDiv h5 {
  color: red;
}
.myDiv h5 * {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <h5>
    <strong>News header</strong> 2015-03-05
  </h5>
</div>
```

However, your edit asks for showing/hiding of the date!

Unfortunately this cannot be achieved because hiding a parent element will also hide all the child elements within i.e. hiding `.mdDiv h5` will hide *everything* inside it.

The only way to hide it separately is to place it within it's own element e.g.

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <h5>
    <strong>News header</strong> <span>2015-03-05</span>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Then you can attack it with `.myDiv h5 span { display: none }`

Comment: Your code snippet works here, but when I try to hide the date (which is what I try to do) it hides everything inside the h5-tag.

Comment: Here's one more option on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r58qs4op/)

Comment: @sand ah, you never specified that! Unfortunately when you hide an element, it hides all of the child elements too. The only way round this is to put the thing you want to hide in its own separate element.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the original post with that detail. I see, thanks for your help!

Comment: @sand answer updated too.

Comment: @sand there you go, I've updated the previous [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r58qs4op/1/) . Hope this helps

Comment: @gvee based on what @sand said "I don't have access to the html, just the css." so that solution won't work for him. And pass `display: none` for the current markup also will not help. So I suggested in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r58qs4op/1/) to set the unwrapped text (which is date in our case) to `font-size: 0`. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

not too sure of you try to achieve. if it is about styling color or bg, then overwrite css for the strong element:

```css
h5 {
  color:purple;
  background:yellow;
  display:table;
}
h5 strong {
  color:yellow;
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <h5>
    <strong>News header</strong> 2015-03-05
  </h5>
</div>
```